# Choose the instance upon unserialization

Tags: php, serialization

I'm writing a PHP class similar to Java's [Currency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Currency.html):

> The class is designed so that there's never more than one Currency instance for any given currency. Therefore, there's no public constructor. You obtain a Currency instance using the getInstance methods.

It's fairly easy with PHP to keep a static array of instantiated objects, and perform a lookup in `getInstance()` to return an existing instance, or instantiate it if needed.

The problem comes with serialization. Even if I implement [Serializable](http://php.net/manual/en/class.serializable.php), I have no way to choose the instance I want to return in `unserialize()`, as the object is already instantiated at this point, and because in PHP you cannot override `$this`:

```php
class Currency implements Serializable
{
    public function getInstance()
    {
        // ...
    }

    public function serialize()
    {
        // ...
    }

    public function unserialize($data)
    {
        // At this point, the object is already instantiated,
        // so I can't just return self::getInstance(),
        // and can't override $this
    }
}
```

**Is there any technical solution to choose the instance to return upon unserialization?**

-- edit --

This is the use case I'm trying to solve:

```php
$euro = Currency::getInstance('EUR');
assert($euro === unserialize(serialize($euro));
```

I know that I can build a *similar* object with `unserialize()`, but I'm wondering if it's ever possible to get the *same* object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**td;dr;** No, you can't do this natively in PHP, because `unserialize()` doesn't support the same `readResolve()` functionality as Java does.

In Java, on deserialization, a new instance of an object is created, its state is restored, then `readResolve()` is invoked on the class, if it exists. `readResolve()` takes the newly created deserialized object, then resolves it to another object (if needed), at which point the resolved object is what's returned from deserialization. The new instance that was originally created is left to be garbage collected if `readResolve()` returned a different object than the one that was supplied to it.

In PHP, there is no such hook within `unserialize()`. You can implement a workaround, however, define your own resolve method to emulate `readResolve()`, but you would be required to call it after `unserialize()`.

```
class Currency implements Serializable {
    private $currencyCode;
    private static $instances = array();

    private function __construct( $currencyCode) {
        $this->currencyCode = $currencyCode;
    }

    public static function getInstance( $currencyCode) {
        if( !isset( self::$instances[$currencyCode])) {
            self::$instances[$currencyCode] = new Currency( $currencyCode);
        }
        return self::$instances[$currencyCode];
    }

    public function serialize() {
        return serialize( $this->currencyCode);
    }

    public function unserialize( $data) {
        $this->currencyCode = unserialize( $data);
    }

    public static function resolve( $obj) {
        $new = self::getInstance( $obj->currencyCode);
        if( $new !== $obj) {
            unset( $obj);
        }
        return $new;
    }
}

$euro = Currency::getInstance('EUR');
assert($euro === Currency::resolve( unserialize(serialize($euro))));
```

Of course, there is nothing stopping somebody from not calling `Currency::resolve()`, and you will then end up with more than one object for the given currency code.

Comment: That answers my question. Thanks!

Comment: @Benjamin - You're welcome! Sorry, I misinterpreted your question to start out with.